# How can I call the model attached to the store in Extjs

Tags: extjs, model, store, attachment, sencha-architect

I have a simple problem in extjs, I don't know how to solve it.

The Problem this:

For example: `var store = Ext.getStore('myproject.store.City');`

this simple method.

I want to do same for the model

For example: `var model = Ext.getModel('myproject.model.City')`

But this doesn't work.

How can I call the model attached to the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it.

Following The Code:`var model = Ext.create('myproject.model.City')`